# Getting illegal domain although adding the domain on google recaptcha

Tags: google-chrome, captcha

I am testing a website before moving to production, so I added to the host file the binding of the website `172.29.28.1 lc-hatavot-test.co.il`   I added to google recaptcha domain `lc-hatavot-test.co.il`,but still getting the error of illegal website. why?

web.config on Captcha settings:

```
<add key="UseGoogleReCaptch" value="true" />
  <add name="MSCaptchaImage" path="CaptchaImage.axd" verb="GET" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <add assembly="MSCaptcha" namespace="MSCaptcha" tagPrefix="Captcha" />
```